# Deploy a Grails App and a custom plugin in Heroku

Tags: java, grails, heroku, deployment, grails-plugin

How can I deploy a Grails App including a Grails custom plugin on heroku?

**Folders:**
app-web/ (Grails Project)
app-core/ (Grails Plugin)

Then, I'm using this intp BuildConfig (app-web)
**grails.plugin.location.'app-core' = "../app-core"**

What is the best way to deploy this into Heroku?

Comment: Best solution so far it will be using git submodules. You can read more about it. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules

Comment: Have you successfully done this?

Comment: Yes. I used git submodules. Maybe this link will help you. http://grails.io/post/138665751278/grails-3-gradle-multi-project-builds